# BotDetect Captcha not loading

Tags: c#, asp.net, captcha, botdetect

I included BotDetect Captcha in my login page but the captcha control is not loading. I tried a simple page based on examples but still captcha is not working/loading

Here are the config lines : [webconfig](https://a.uguu.se/OdBQb4Ti2FmS_web.config)
[image]

Your help is highly needed and appreciated

Comment: Probably it will not work for localhost

Comment: You mean, i can only check and test it through a staging/deployed environment?

Comment: Yes, you can try virtual host as well but would suggest to test in staging first.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Is there an alternative captcha were i can test it and debug on vs?

Comment: did you solve it? i have the same issue

Comment: Yes. I notice that if via localhost, botcaptcha is not working.
If you want to test it, better to have a staging server for trial and test.

Answer (score 0):

You can try reCAPTCHA which have provision to run on local

"If you would like to use "localhost" for development, you must add it to the list of domains."

Even though it allows to run on local server but can only work if you access localhost using 127.0.0.1 rather than localhost.

Here is the reCAPTCHA .[link](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/v3.html) for reference